# Static Analysis to detect Buffer Overrun on Visual Studio C++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Following code writes into invalid area in memory but there's no compilation error.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* s1 = new char[10];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) s1[i]='a';
    cout << s1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In runtime the code terminates with return code 0 printing 20 a's then some garbage before it met 0 but I assume this is very dangerous as it could contaminate  / illegally access other area in memory.

Is there any way such mistake can be detected in compile time? Or at least a runtime exception raised pointing straight into `s1[i]='a'` line?

Setting /RTCs and /GS flag as recommended in other posts did not help.

Running Visual Studio code analysis (ANALZYE -> Run Code Analysis) gives no result either.

There are list of tools third party tools posted in here: [C++ static code analysis tool on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97454/c-static-code-analysis-tool-on-windows) but I'm hoping there's a way this can be detected by Visual Studio alone?

Answer (score 3):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c.aspx, /GS (Buffer Security Check) is carried out in run-time, not in compile type.

/RTCs (according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx) controls run-time checks. So neither of these two switches were designed to do static analysis of your code. That's, they are not supposed to detect your problem at compile time.

I think static code analysis is still in research stage in general, I'd be surprised that VS 2012 would provide full fledged support.

Another possibility is that the specific types of error you are trying to detect is an array-out-of-bound error. Buffer-overrun may not be the right keyword to do search.

Comment: /analyze in VS 2012 has been in heavy use at Microsoft for many, many years. The technology was first made publicly available in VS 2005, but was used well before that internally. That said, the purpose of /analyze is to validate the contracts between functions and callers that are annotated with SAL and not basic coding errors.